# Plot depending on dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, if-statement

I load a single file into three dataframes:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', names=['Time', '60Ni', '61Ni', '62Ni', '63Cu', '64Ni', '65Cu', '66Zn'], skiprows=6, nrows=50, index_col=False, dtype=float)
data2 = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', names=['Time', '60Ni', '61Ni', '62Ni', '63Cu', '64Ni', '65Cu', '66Zn'], skiprows=56, nrows=50, index_col=False, dtype=float)
data3 = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', names=['Time', '60Ni', '61Ni', '62Ni', '63Cu', '64Ni', '65Cu', '66Zn'], skiprows=106, nrows=50, index_col=False, dtype=float)
```

I would like to plot them depending on the used dataframe:

For data:

```
fig.savefig(outfile_plt + basename + "_1_filtered.png", dpi=150)
```

For data2:

```
fig.savefig(outfile_plt + basename + "_2_filtered.png", dpi=150)
```

For data3:

```
fig.savefig(outfile_plt + basename + "_3_filtered.png", dpi=150)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can read and plot the data in a loop `for rows_to_skip, set_id in zip([6,56,196], [1,2,3]):` and then `data = pd.read_csv(..., skip_rows=rows_to_skip)` and `fig.savefig(outfile_plt + basename + "_" + str(set_id) + "_filtered.png"`. Note that your question is a basic programming question, not specific to dataframes or matplotlib.

Comment: Thx. But isn't there a possibility to do it without changing the pd.read? I know that it is a basic programming question but I needed to add several tags.